# SSIS packages import multiple excel files with missing columns in some files

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have problem and I can not find the answer. I Have cca 2000 excel files and I need import data from this files into MSSQL table using by SSIS packages. I have a set procedure With Foreach Loop Container. All running fine, until.... In some excel files is column 'NOTE' but in some files not. And then my scrip fall down with this error message:

> [Excel Source [2]] Warning: The external columns for Excel Source are out of synchronization with the data source columns. The Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].ExternalColumns[NOTE] needs to be removed from the external columns.

How I can fix this?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; the definition of the Excel file does not match the definition defined in your Source node. SSIS *must* have the columns *explicitly* defined. If a column may or may not appear, it won't be able to process the file when the definition is different to what you've told it it is. Ideally you should be ensuring your files all have the same definition.

Comment: Yes, I know, that  my problem lies in the missing column 'NOTE'. But I have 2000 excel files so I can control for each one if the column is there or not. So I have to set up a process that ensures that if the column is found in the file, it fills in the values and if not, it fills in the empty values. Have you any Idea?

Comment: The alternative would be to have two different data flows and then programmatically use the one that is correct for that file, one Dataflow for files with the Note column and another for those that don't. If you know which do and don't have the column then this would be easier. If you don't, this becomes harder. SSIS if *not* a good tool when you don't know what the definition of the source data will be. This is why I suggest that you make the files consistent, as then the problem disappears.

Comment: Are these excel files or csv? You can use source script component and write a dynamic mapping script with dot net. here are some examples https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-column-mapping-in-ssis-sqlbulkcopy-class-vs-data-flow/

Comment: I have 2000 excel files, so it is not possible to fix all files. And what for example Split Component o detect if the column is present or not and if not, to fill it with null?

Comment: It os excel files (xlsx.